# Apply border to the region that occupies margin of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container which has a fixed width of 200px and the rest of the width is margin equally on both sides. 
I have applied margin-bottom on this container but it will occupy only the 200px width since that is the width of the container box.
How can i make the border-bottom occupy the entire screen width.

**code:**

```css
.sch-container{
  max-width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="sch-container">
    <div class="content">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/16yLLf68/#&togetherjs=uelP25pzHa)

Comment: In the [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model), the margin is the outermost region. Assuming margin to be greater than zero, neither content nor border can be as wide as it. If that's what you want, then you will need an abutting element, styled with suitable CSS directives.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing as two class will be the best choice.

```css
.sch-container{
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
.content{
  max-width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sch-container">
   <div class="content">
     Hello
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a straight forward solution to your problem, more of an alternative.
You could use `<hr />` tag instead of `border-bottom` on `.sch-container`.

```css
.sch-container{
  max-width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
hr{
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid; 
}
.red{
 border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Some Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sch-container">
    <div class="content">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="red"/> 
</body>
</html>
```